# MongoDB, загрузка одного атрибута

Tags: mongodb

Здраствуйте, такой вопрос:
Можно ли загрузить только один атрибут из документа по заданому id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот например

```
db.inventory.find( { _id: "id" }, { attr: 1, status: 1 } )
```

загрузит только поля `attr` и `status` для объекта.

Подробнее в документации https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/